# how to convert a string to a polyline path in google map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have a String variable:

```
var street= "33.87928761152994,35.486247539520264,33.86875861815386, 35.486247539520264,33.86008146647083, 35.48592567443848";
```

i want it to be converted to a polyline path:

```
road = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: convertedStreet,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor:color,
strokeOpacity: 1.3,
strokeWeight:HW
        });
        road.setMap(map);
```

Comment: For plotting one point you required pair of lat and lng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare path as below.

```
convertedStreet.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Loop through your values and push it in ***convertedStreet*** variable.

You can split your string and use it in above example:

```
var arr=street.split(',');
```

In your Question i am considering after split by , odd number is **lat** and even number value is **lng**.

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)
{
     convertedStreet.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[i]),parseFloat(arr[i+1] ));

} 

road = new google.maps.Polyline({
   path: convertedStreet,
   geodesic: true,
   strokeColor:color,
   strokeOpacity: 1.3,
   strokeWeight:HW
});
road.setMap(map);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXBa6/)